# How to replace a substring with ( from a string

Tags: java, android, string, replace

I have a string like following

```
Want to Start (A) Programming and (B) Designing
```

I want to replace `(A)` with `\n(A)` and `(B)` with `\n(B)`
So ,the expected result will be like

```
Want to Start
(A) Programming and 
(B) Designing
```

I've tried

```
stringcontent=stringcontent.replaceAll("(A)", "\n(A)");
```

It's not working. After searching in google, I realized  its because of  special characters `(` and `)` in string.

Any possible way to solve this?

Comment: Where is the special character &?!

Comment: Did you read a bit further what makes those characters special and how you deal with it? It's all in the documentation of replaceAll()

Comment: I mean - ( & ). hope u understand what i mean.

Comment: @NitzRaj `(&)` was misleading.

Comment: ( and ) :P .
Dont mention : as misleading :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex

```
String a = "Want to Start (A) Programming and (B) Designing";
String b = a.replaceAll("\\(", "\n\\(");
System.out.println(b);
```

results in

```
Want to Start 
(A) Programming and 
(B) Designing
```

Just escape the brackets with `\\` and you're fine.

Edit:
more specific, like mentioned below

`a.replaceAll("(\\([AB]\\))", "\n$1");` to match only (A) and (B) or

`a.replaceAll("(\\(\\w\\))", "\n$1");` to match any (*) (Word character)

Comment: By the question you should probably amend the regex to be "(\\(\w\\))" and the replacement to be "\n$1" so it matches only the parameters the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the special characters:

```
stringcontent=stringcontent.replaceAll("\\(A\\)", "\n(A)");
```

Comment: Thanks dude its somewhat right answer. Here is the real one
stringcontent=stringcontent.replaceAll("\\(A\\)", "\n\\(A\\)");

Answer (score 0):

As first argument method replaceAll expects regular expression and I highly recommend you to read about them.

```
stringcontent.replaceAll("\\((?=\\w\\))", "\n(");
```

**EDIT:**

Proposed answers use hardcoded letter for checking and replacement (or assume that there is no text in braces). My answer uses \w wildcard that matches with letter together with advanced checking that makes sure letter and closing brace follows your opening brace. 
What answer to use is up to you.